# Should you include multiple low-pass capacitor circuits in integrated IC PCB design?

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, pcb, integrated-circuit, low-pass

[image: Circuit Design for PCB]I have two circuits, one is a POE to 5V, another is an IC for leds. They both include capacitors between 5v and gnd. Should I include the first 5V circuit POE capacitors since it should already be doing the filtering?
Transformer for POE:
https://www.coilcraft.com/de-de/products/transformers/power-transformers/power-converter-transformers/fct1-xxm22sl/fct1-50m22sl/
POE datasheet:
https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP8009GV-Z/document_id/4873/
LED Current Regulator:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/lumissil-microsystems/IS31FL3236A-QFLS4-TR/14308348
Or is there something I am missing. Here are the schematics:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Wes Ellgass -  Hi, To comply with the site rule on [referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] your question & add the PDF / video / webpage name & *link* to the source of each copied / adapted image. TY

Comment: Wes Ellgass - Thanks for adding some links. However the images you copied into your question do not appear (as far as I can see) on the Digikey pages you linked. Please link to the actual source pages / documents which contain the original images which you adapted (cropped etc.) and posted here. TY

Comment: Sam, its from the documentation in the pdfs. What do you need?

Comment: Wes Ellgass - Re: "*its from the documentation in the pdfs. What do you need?*" Then please link to the respective PDFs, if those are the sources of the two images. The requirement is to link to the source(s) (if they are online) of any copied/adapted material. So if those schematics are in some PDFs, please add the links to those PDFs. TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capacitors for the LED driver are necessary for stabilizing the chip - they decouple the power supply and provide local noise immunity. If you want a robust design, keep the capacitors. Also, they prevent disturbing the VCC plane that other IC's are using especially if this LED driver modulates via PWM.

Will the circuit work with out them? Probably. But it's bad design practice - it's a lot of risk for practically no cost or effort.

Comment: C2A, C2B, and C2C are already doing this though, since the LED driver is directly pulling from VOut and VOgnd, then why put two more capacitors in parallel?

Comment: Those resistors you mention are on the order of tens of uF's and likely electrolytic. They are great for storing large energy but have poor high-frequency performance. They will not suffice for high frequency decoupling that I mentioned. Generally, the the lower the capacitor value, the better the high frequency performance.

Comment: In addition, since the transformer has grounding 5V side detection, couldn't adding capacitors trigger this reset on start?

Comment: What transformer? And what reset on start? Please clarify.

Comment: "Short-Circuit Protection (SCP)
When the output is shorted to ground, the
MP8009 works in OCP mode. The current is
limited cycle by cycle, and OLP may be
triggered.
If the peak current cannot be limited by a
160mV SENSE voltage in every cycle due to
the minimum gate on time, the current may
become unstable and the transformer may
saturate. If the monitored SENSE voltage
reaches 300mV, the GATE pin turns off and
runs hiccup mode immediately with a 340ms off
time."

Comment: @WesEllgass You're going to have to post that as whole separate question as it is off-topic from this one. Briefly speaking, the decoupling caps I mention have no bearing on OVP, OCP, or SCP. Totally separate issue and needs a question of it's own.